# Angular + Springboot : How do I make the Routed angular app fallback to index.html from server side?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

The front-end of my application is in Angular and the services are written using Spring Boot. My angular code and services code is hosted on two different urls.

Problem:
When I reload any page, it gives me Error 404 not found.

I want to implement the solution mentioned in the following link under the server configuration part: 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback

How do I pass the index.html page from the server side to angular when they are hosted on 2 different links?

Comment: Why would you use anything UI related on your server side while you have Angular app for that? You have UI, you have API, use rest to communicate between those two and Bob's your uncle. Btw, reloading is not something you often do in Single Page Applications.

Comment: When the user reloads the page then we get the Error-404

Answer (score 1):

I have developed an app which has the same architecture, i.e. Spring for backend, Angular for frontend.

What I'd like to in this scenario is to have a suffix for angular app as follows

```java
@Controller
public class InitController {

    @GetMapping("/ng-app/**")
    public String handleNgApp(Model model) {
        return "ng-app/index";
    }
```

And provide following config as template resolver. I use `thymeleaf` but you can use anything.

```java
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/"); // /WEB-INF/ or classpath:/templates/
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5"); // HTML5 or LEGACYHTML5
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return templateResolver;
}
```

And finally, when I build my angular application, I set the output path as follows

`ng build --prod  -op=<root-directory-of-spring>/src/main/resources/templates/ng-app`

`-op` aka `output-path` is for angular-cli to know where to put the complied resources.

With this setup, when user comes to your application and navigates to a child route, let's call it `home`, the address bar will look like this: `yourdomain.com/ng-app/home`.

When you hit refresh button, the browser will make a request to `/ng-app/home` which will be handled by `InitController`. Then, the angular app will be returned and angular will navigate to the route `home`. Everyone will be happy.